# A Good JSON Database Library?

Tags: json, node.js, database, npm, storage

I am using Node.js...

---

Personally, I'm not a fan of SQL. What I do like is JSON, and I would like to be able to store my server data as JSON.

Even though it's possible to just `JSON.parse` and `.stringify` the process, I get the impression that doing this is a bad idea for large-scale applications.

Also, it would be nice if the database library could be just a *library*, and not a server like with MySQL.

Any suggestions on where to find said library would be much appreciated.

---

Availability of said library on NPM would be brilliant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use low db befor for small nodejs projects. Its easy to use. See documentation.
Have fun.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/lowdb